# Annotation_custom does not position table grob on the ggplot at specified position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted a summary table on ggplot2, with

```
annotation_custom(tableGrob(SummaryTable), xmin=xmin ,xmax = xmax)
```

Everything works well except, that summary table does not follow exact data position specified, it needs to be manually adjusted by looking at chart and for each different variable chart it works but with some offet to xmin and xmax values. As per help in R, xmin and xmax are data coordinates. I just want to place grob on right corner of the main plot. There are many chart in this project, running on same code. I can manually center each chart a xmin and xmax value, but such work is tedioous and I want to keep it automatic with vectorized operation.

I already saw many questions asking similar issues, but in all (what I could find) solution was with some other way, like using gtable/viewport/ggsave etc.

I am already giving final touch to my work, so my first need is to find if at all annotation_custom can do this job well or not? Certainly its ideal to learn new alternatives and this is how we learn, but please point out if my existing work can be done current solution in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could understand how annotation_custom works and how to dynamically center the positions somewhat precisely.

I again read the R help deeply and it states:
**"annotation_custom expects the grob to fill the entire viewport defined by xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax. Grobs with a different (absolute) size will be center-justified in that region. Inf values can be used to fill the full plot panel (see examples)."**

So now interpreted this way, that table visual shall be plotted center justified if xmin and xmax are defined differently (not Inf so), and this means my current output was appearing right but center justified.

I now made another vector, in my case it was xmin=(Avg+Max)/2 and xmax=Inf. So at least the table prints are defined position.

Though I need to fine tune the formula incase just need to touch the extremes of the plot. But my purpose is served.